# Encountering 'Unexpected token '??=' when utilizing vite-plugin-dts in a React application

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm utilizing Vite for my React-based library and aiming to obtain the declaration files during the build process. However, after running the build, I encounter the following error.

[image]

I have thoroughly examined both the tsconfig.json and vite.config.ts files for any errors, but they appear to be error-free. Despite this, I continue to encounter the aforementioned error.

Here is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES6", "DOM", "ES2021.String", "ES2017.Object"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "declaration": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./dist/index.d.ts"],

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "./index.ts"],
  "exclude": ["build", "node_modules"]
}
```

vite.config.ts

```
// vite.config.js
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";

export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    target: "es6",
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/Index.ts'),
      name: 'vite-react-app',
      fileName: (format) => (format === "umd" ? "index.umd.js" : "index.es.js"),
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['react', "react-dom"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: 'React',
          "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
        },
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [react(), dts()]
});
```

Comment: The modern browser build now targets safari14 by default for wider ES2020 compatibility (bumped from safari13). This means that modern builds can now use BigInt and that the nullish coalescing operator isn't transpiled anymore. If you need to support older browsers, you can add @vitejs/plugin-legacy as usual. Link : https://main.vitejs.dev/guide/migration.html

Comment: Thanks @HumanoidMk.12, tried the above but no luck, still getting the same error

Comment: This issue was fixed after upgrading node to the latest version